# AIX / Unix - Delete files older than x days

Tags: unix, aix, xargs, rm

I have been struggling with this one for quite a few days now.  It seems simple enough but I cannot seem to find the right command or arguments needed to accomplish this (seemingly) simple task.  I need to delete wildcarded files in a directory older than x days.  I have tried the following to no avail and I am wondering if the wildcard is possibly the problem.

```
find /path/to/files/ -name file_* -mtime +45 -exec rm '{}' +
find /path/to/files/ -name file_* -mtime +45 -exec rm {} ;\
find /path/to/files/ -name file_* -mtime +45 | xargs rm
```

The find works fine, it lists the correct files.  It's the deletion that is not working.

Comment: maybe `find /path/to/files/ -name "file_*" -mtime +45 -delete`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the wildcard to `find`by protecting it from shell expansion and despecialized the final `;`:

```
find /path/to/files/ -name "file_*" -mtime +45 -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the following code WAS working properly for me:

```
find /path/to/files/ -name file_* -mtime +45 -exec rm '{}' +
```

Comment: Only if you run it in a directory where the wildcard doesn't match anything. The correct and robust solution is to quote the wildcard, like in @Jean-Baptiste's answer.

Answer (score 0):

For AIX 6.1, there is a slight change needed. Verbose explanation included (fair warning)

find . /path/to/files/ -name "Files*.*" -mtime +45 -exec

That dot is needed. For the "Files*.*" you will use your names. My folder is a custom report folder and the date of the file is included in the name. But all the reports start with "Daily". So I have "Daily*.*". Each day we generate 2 reports. The specific report name is sandwiched between "Daily" and the date it was generated in the file name. So Daily*.* gets them all. I have been unsuccessful in using "*.*". This may be specific to AIX 6.1, which is what we are using. AIX commands can vary by version.

Good luck!

Comment: Sounds like another question (if a bit unclear question).